# Android SQlite Databases Can't get value from databases

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have android Sqlite databases having four table, i want to get value of custumer_data "cust_id" every where in the activity when ever i need. I get value of cust_id in activity but when i implement same method in another activity i  value of cust_id is shows null.
Here is my database class:

```
public class SctDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
Cursor cursor;
private static final String LOG = "sctDatabaseHelper";
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "sctnetwork";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String TABLE_CUSTIMER_DATA = "customer_data";
private static final String TABLE_FRIEND_LIST = "friend_list";
private static final String TABLE_PROFILE = "profile";
private static final String TABLE_REGISTRATION_FLAG = "registration_flag";

//element of table custumer data
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_APP_LOCK = "app_lock";
private static final String KEY_CURR_CODE = "curr_code";
private static final String KEY_CURR_TYPE = "curr_type";
private static final String KEY_CUST_ID_CUSTUMER = "cust_id";
private static final String KEY_FIRST_NAME = "first_name";
private static final String KEY_LAST_NAME = "last_name";
private static final String KEY_L_PIN = "l_pin";
private static final String KEY_PIN_FLAG = "pin_flag";
private static final String KEY_PIN_RETRIES_COUNT = "pin_retries_count";
private static final String KEY_RESET_PIN = "reset_pin";

//element of table friend list

private static final String KEY_CELL_NO = "cell_no";
private static final String KEY_CUST_ID_FRIEND = "cust_id";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";

//element of table profile
private static final String KEY_ACT_FLAG = "act_flag";
private static final String KEY_CARD_TYPE = "card_type";
private static final String KEY_EXP_DATE = "exp_date";
private static final String KEY_LAST_FOUR = "last_4";
private static final String KEY_PROFILE_NAME = "profile_name";

//element of table registration flag
private static final String KEY_REG_FLAG = "reg_flag";

//crete table custumer data
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_CUSTUMER_DATA = "create table " + TABLE_CUSTIMER_DATA + "(" + KEY_ID + " integer primary key, " + KEY_CUST_ID_CUSTUMER + " text ," + KEY_APP_LOCK + " text, " + KEY_CURR_CODE + " text, " + KEY_CURR_TYPE + " text, " + KEY_FIRST_NAME + " text, " + KEY_LAST_NAME + " text ," + KEY_L_PIN + " text ," + KEY_PIN_FLAG + " text, " + KEY_PIN_RETRIES_COUNT + " text, " + KEY_RESET_PIN + " text " + ")";
//create table friend list
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_FRIEND_LIST = "create table " + TABLE_FRIEND_LIST + "(" + KEY_CELL_NO + " text, " + KEY_CUST_ID_FRIEND + " text, " + KEY_NAME + " text " + ")";
// create table profile
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_PROFILE = " create table " + TABLE_PROFILE + "(" + KEY_ACT_FLAG + " text, " + KEY_CARD_TYPE + " text ," + KEY_EXP_DATE + " text, " + KEY_LAST_FOUR + " text, " + KEY_PROFILE_NAME + " text " + ")";

// create table of registration flag
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_FLAG = " create table " + TABLE_REGISTRATION_FLAG + "(" + KEY_REG_FLAG + " text " + ")";


public SctDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_CUSTUMER_DATA);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_FLAG);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_FRIEND_LIST);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_PROFILE);
    Log.d("custumer_data", CREATE_TABLE_CUSTUMER_DATA);
    Log.d("flag", CREATE_TABLE_FLAG);
    Log.d("friend_list", CREATE_TABLE_FRIEND_LIST);
    Log.d("profile", CREATE_TABLE_PROFILE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CUSTIMER_DATA);
    db.execSQL("DROP IF EXISTS " + TABLE_FRIEND_LIST);
    db.execSQL("DROP IF EXISTS " + TABLE_REGISTRATION_FLAG);
    db.execSQL("DROP IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PROFILE);

}

public long createCustumer(Customer_Data customer_data) {
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(KEY_APP_LOCK, customer_data.getApp_lock());
    values.put(KEY_FIRST_NAME, customer_data.getFirst_name());
    values.put(KEY_LAST_NAME, customer_data.getLast_name());
    values.put(KEY_L_PIN, customer_data.getL_pin());
    values.put(KEY_PIN_FLAG, customer_data.getPin_flag());
    values.put(KEY_PIN_RETRIES_COUNT, customer_data.getPin_retries_count());
    values.put(KEY_RESET_PIN, customer_data.getReset_pin());

    long custumer = sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_CUSTIMER_DATA, null, values);
    return custumer;
}

public long insertProfile( String expdate, String last_4,String flag,String Dummy) {
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(KEY_EXP_DATE, expdate);
    contentValues.put(KEY_LAST_FOUR, last_4);
    contentValues.put(KEY_ACT_FLAG,flag);
    contentValues.put(KEY_PROFILE_NAME,Dummy);
    return sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_PROFILE, null, contentValues);

}
public long insertProfile(String cardtype) {
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(KEY_CARD_TYPE, cardtype);
    return sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_PROFILE, null, contentValues);

}

public long insertCutid(String str) {
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_CUST_ID_CUSTUMER, str);
    return sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_CUSTIMER_DATA, null, values);
}

public long insertCtypeCcode(String type, String code) {
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_CURR_TYPE, type);
    values.put(KEY_CURR_CODE, code);
    return sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_CUSTIMER_DATA, null, values);
}

public long insertFLname(String first, String last) {
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_FIRST_NAME, first);
    values.put(KEY_LAST_NAME, last);
    return sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_CUSTIMER_DATA, null, values);
}

public long createProfile(Profile profile) {
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_ACT_FLAG, profile.getAct_flag());
    values.put(KEY_CARD_TYPE, profile.getCard_type());
    values.put(KEY_EXP_DATE, profile.getExp_date());
    values.put(KEY_LAST_FOUR, profile.getLast_4());
    values.put(KEY_PROFILE_NAME, profile.getProfile_name());
    long profileinsert = sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_PROFILE, null, values);
    return profileinsert;
}

public long createFriendlist(Friends_List friends_list) {
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_CELL_NO, friends_list.getCell_no());
    values.put(KEY_CUST_ID_CUSTUMER, friends_list.getCust_id());
    values.put(KEY_NAME, friends_list.getName());
    long friendlistinsert = sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_FRIEND_LIST, null, values);
    return friendlistinsert;
}

public long createRegFlag(String str) {
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_REG_FLAG, str);
    long regflaginsert = sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_REGISTRATION_FLAG, null, values);
    return regflaginsert;
}

public int checkHasCustData() {
    boolean data;
    String selectquery = "select * from " + TABLE_CUSTIMER_DATA;
    Log.d("custumer", selectquery);
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectquery, null);
    int custmr_count = cursor.getCount();
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return custmr_count;
}

public int checkRegData() {
    boolean flag;
    String selectquery = " select * from " + TABLE_REGISTRATION_FLAG;
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(selectquery, null);
    int reg_count = cursor.getCount();
    cursor.close();
    sqLiteDatabase.close();
    return reg_count;

}

public String getCu_id() {
    String bankbalresult = null;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String selectquery = "select cust_id from  customer_data";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectquery, null);
    if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        do {
            bankbalresult = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("cust_id"));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return bankbalresult;
}

public String getFlag() {
    String bankbalresult = null;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String selectquery = "select reg_flag from  registration_flag";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectquery, null);
    if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        do {
            bankbalresult = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("reg_flag"));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return bankbalresult;
}

public int updateFlag(String str) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues value = new ContentValues();
    value.put(KEY_REG_FLAG, str);
    return db.update(TABLE_REGISTRATION_FLAG, value, KEY_REG_FLAG + " = ?", new String[]{str});

}
```

}

And code use to acess cust_id in activity is:

```
    private SctDatabaseHelper sctDatabaseHelper;

   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        sctDatabaseHelper = new SctDatabaseHelper(this);
        sctDatabaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    }
```

and i get `cust_id` using this:

```
 String id = sctDatabaseHelper.getCu_id();
```

by using this i get value of `cust_id` in one activity but used same method to other but cant get.
Whats the issue ? help me

Answer (score 0):

In your `customer_data` table, you have created `id` as primary key.

When you are creating your table, you have not declared your primary key as auto-increment and when you insert into the table, you are not providing any id.

Thus, when you insert, your primary key is not being formed as you desire.

Try something like this

```
//crete table custumer data
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_CUSTUMER_DATA = "create table " + TABLE_CUSTIMER_DATA + "(" + KEY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + KEY_CUST_ID_CUSTUMER + " text ," + KEY_APP_LOCK + " text, " + KEY_CURR_CODE + " text, " + KEY_CURR_TYPE + " text, " + KEY_FIRST_NAME + " text, " + KEY_LAST_NAME + " text ," + KEY_L_PIN + " text ," + KEY_PIN_FLAG + " text, " + KEY_PIN_RETRIES_COUNT + " text, " + KEY_RESET_PIN + " text " + ");";
```

I have also noticed that in the create table strings, you haven't added ';' at the end.

You need to change you activity code to something like this-

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        sctDatabaseHelper = new SctDatabaseHelper(this);
        sct.getCu_id();

    }
```

You also need to change your `getCu_id()` method to something like this

```
public String getCu_id() {
    String bankbalresult = null;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String selectquery = "select "+KEY_CUST_ID_CUSTUMER+" from "+TABLE_CUSTIMER_DATA+";";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectquery, null);
    if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        for(c.moveToFirst();!c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext())
            bankbalresult = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_CUST_ID_CUSTUMER));
        } 
    }
    return bankbalresult;
}
```

This will give you the last customer id stored in your table.

If you want all the Customer ids that are stored, then you can do something like this

```
 public String getCu_id() {
        String bankbalresult = null;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String selectquery = "select "+KEY_CUST_ID_CUSTUMER+" from "+TABLE_CUSTIMER_DATA+";";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectquery, null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            for(c.moveToFirst();!c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext())
                bankbalresult+ = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_CUST_ID_CUSTUMER))+"!";
            } 
        }
        return bankbalresult;
    }
```

Then you can `split` your string at '!' and form an array of all the customer ids.

In your `select` statements, you haven't added `;` at the end. 
Hope this helps :)

Comment: "cust_id" still getting null

Comment: 'public String getCu_id() {
    String bankbalresult = null;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String selectquery = "select id from  customer_data;";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectquery, null);
    cursor=moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("cust_id"))
}'  check if you are getting correct value

Comment: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.